# Mercurial: include revisions in git diff?

Tags: mercurial

Is there some way to ask Mercurial to show the revisions being diffed in the output when using git mode? For example:

```
$ hg diff -r trunk:development
diff -r 08d51ecf22cf:ff5673e55b9f --git a/foo.c b/foo.c
...
```

Or something similar?

I've found that there have been a few times that I've taken a diff (eg, to review), but have later been unable to recreate it because I've forgotten which revisions it was taken against.

**Edit**: the `-v` flag will show revisions in normal diff mode, but I've got to use git diff (I deal with binary files fairly regularly).

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
hg diff -v
```

Comment: This works, but only if git diff mode isn't used (making it useless when I've got to diff binary data)… Any other way?